# Feh outputs "(image link) does not exist" when inputting a https link from a bash variable

Tags: bash, curl, feh

I have this bash script which basically 60 times every 0.1s will fetch an random image using a image API and display it using feh at a random postion on my screen.

Now running `feh -g 500x500+10+10 --scale-down "https://example.com/example-image.png"` works and it downloads and renders a image.

But my script just returns "(image link) does not exist".

```bash
for line in $(cat ~/bin/img-num.txt)
do
    sleep 0.1s
    X=$(shuf -i 1-2100 -n 1)
    Y=$(shuf -i 1-1100 -n 1)
    image=$(curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET https://api.waifu.pics/sfw/waifu | cut -f2,3 -d":" | cut -f1 -d"}")
    feh -g 500x500+$X+$Y --scale-down "$image" &
done
```

I tested setting image variable in a terminal and running that same feh command but it returns the same error.

Comment: To get some useful hints add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script and then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: `$image` contains literal double-quotes, which make the URL invalid. You want quotes *around* the URL, not *in* the URL.

Comment: `for line in $(cat ~/bin/img-num.txt)` is an anti-pattern, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Davisson said.

`$image` contains literal double-quotes, which make the URL invalid. You want quotes around the URL, not in the URL.

This was fixed by changing the image command to this.

`curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET https://api.waifu.pics/sfw/waifu | cut -f2,3 -d":" | cut -f2 -d'"'`